# Using Outlook's Zoom plugin with two different Zoom and email accounts, within same profile - How to avoid log in prompt?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar, plugins, zoom-meeting

**Background**: Hi all, sorry if I'm missing anything obvious but I'm helping an end user with 2 emails added to her Outlook for Windows client's profile - and also 2 Zoom accounts. The Zoom accounts belong to each email (she is managing all her boss's IT accounts, yeah not secure but that's their choice.) Zoom accounts are Pro and login is configured with SSO, tied to the email.

**Problem**: She sometimes gets a prompt to log in when scheduling meetings through one of the calendars and I'm 99% sure it's because the Zoom plugin is integrated with the Zoom app which only allows signing into one account at once.

**The Question**: Can anyone share how to avoid the sign in prompt completely in this scenario? For either of the 2 zoom accounts when scheduling a zoom meeting through Outlook calendar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm 99% sure it's because the Zoom plugin is integrated with the Zoom app which only allows signing into one account at once.

Agreed. Seems to me that it's expected to get the sign in prompt with her current configuration, two set of different accounts in a single Outlook profile.

Below are some possible solutions for reference:

1. If the user doesn't need to deal with the two accounts at the same time, it might be better to separate the two accounts into different Outlook profiles so that she can switch between the different profiles.
2. If the user do need to handle these accounts at the same time, she can manage one account in the Outlook desktop client, while manage the other account in Outlook web app (which can also have the Zoom add-in installed)

In addition, you can also reach out to the Zoom community to see if there are other zoom users who have similar experiences.

Comment: Thanks. So I did some testing and tried to replicate the issue on my own computer.  I didn't get the login prompt even once so not sure what how she got signed out at some point. That's because the behavior of the plugin is to always keep you in one Zoom account, even if you're sending from a totally unaffiliated Outlook account! Interesting. It doesn't kick you out, ever. (Admittedly, I tested with 2 zoom accounts that were not tied to SSO and were Basic instead of Pro.)

Comment: I don't see how 2 outlook profiles would help since the problem is tied to Zoom, not Outlook. Zoom doesn't allow simultaneous login. But I could try.                                             And yeah Outlook for the Web or even the Zoom website can work for scheduling different meetings. The truth is that this gets super messy, because she's a delegate of her boss's Zoom and Outlook calendar too. I cannot test that easily on my own. Ugh, this is giving me a headache...